# The below closure example not returning properly

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to implement the below javascript code using closures and I get the output like this. Here the whole function is printed in the browser

```
`function apple(){ var test1 = '
'+ '
'+ ' This is apple'+ '
'+ '
'; return test1; }`
```

Desired output:

I only want "This is apple" to be printed and not the whole function. Please check the code below. Any help greatly appreciated.

javascript code

```
`function init(){

 function fruits(){
         function apple(){
            var test1 = '<div id="main">'+
                  '   <div>'+
                  '   This is apple'+
                  '   </div>'+
                  '</div>';
            return test1;
         }

         function mango(){
            var test2 = '<div id="main">'+
                  '   <div>'+
                  '   This is mango'+
                  '   </div>'+
                  '</div>';
            return test2;
         }

         return{
            apple: apple,
            mango: mango
         }
  }

   function print(var1){
      document.write(var1)
   }

   return {
      fruits:fruits,
      print: print
   }
}`
```

HTML code : which calls the javascript code

```
`<html>
  <head>
     <script src="script.js"></script>

   </head>

  <body>

      <script>

             //creating object for the main function which is init
             var object = init();
             //creating object for the function fruits
             var fruits = object.fruits();
             //passing function apple inside fruits to print function.
             //function apple returns html div.  
               //function print prints the html using document.write 
             object.print(fruits.apple);

      </script>


  </body>

</html> `
```

Comment: You are not calling `fruits.apple`.

Comment: Also if you are indenting your code there is no need for tilda(`) marks because it turns it into strings

Comment: oh.. ok..never knew that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `fruits.apple` somewhere, because it is a function.

I suggest to move the call inside of `print`

```js
function init() {
    function fruits() {
        function apple() {
            return '<div id="main"><div>This is apple</div></div>';
        }

        function mango() {
            return '<div id="main"><div>This is mango</div></div>';
        }
        return { apple, mango };
    }

    function print(fruit) {
        document.write(fruit());
    }

    return { fruits, print };
}

var object = init(),
    fruits = object.fruits();

object.print(fruits.apple);
```